# Moodle throwing Cannot find session record error

Tags: session, moodle

user gets logged out now and then and I'm getting the below error continuously in the error log

> Default exception handler: Incorrect key Debug: \nError code:
> invalidkey\n* line 117 of
> /auth/userkey/classes/core_userkey_manager.php: moodle_exception
> thrown\n* line 152 of /auth/userkey/auth.php: call to
> auth_userkey\core_userkey_manager->validate_key()\n* line 31 of
> /auth/userkey/login.php: call to
> auth_plugin_userkey->user_login_userkey()\n

> Default exception handler: Your session has most likely timed out.
> Please log in again. Debug: \nError code: invalidsesskey\n* line 85 of
> /lib/sessionlib.php: moodle_exception thrown\n* line 33 of
> /mod/quiz/autosave.ajax.php: call to require_sesskey()\n, referer:
> https://examcenter.ccbst.co/mod/quiz/attempt.php?attempt=138511&cmid=10847

Answer (score 1):

`auth_userkey` is a contributed plugin rather than a core Moodle plugin

I would suggest reporting this as a bug to Catalyst via their Github issues - they are a reputable and well known company in the Moodle world, so hopefully will provide an answer quickly

https://github.com/catalyst/moodle-auth_userkey/issues